# What is the difference between "sentence" and "paragraph" in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am playing with the movement command in emacs's C++ mode. 
I found two useful command:

1. <kbd>M-}</kbd> : which the manual says it moves to next
   *paragraph*.
2. <kbd>M-k</kbd>: which the manual says it kills the next *sentence*.

Observation:

1. When I do  <kbd>M-}</kbd>, it moves by **a contiguous code snippet** that has no empty lines in it.
2. When I do  <kbd>M-k</kbd>, it deletes **a contiguous code snippet** that has no empty lines in it.

Question: 
In C++ mode of emacs, does *paragraph* and *sentence* both refer to the same concept: **a contiguous code snippet**?

(Also a related question:) Is there a formal definition of the concepts such as *balanced expression*, and the above *sentence*, *paragraph*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- See (emacs) `Expressions` for what it has to say about *balanced expressions*.
- See (emacs) `Sentences` for what it has to say about *sentences*.
- See (emacs) `Paragraphs` for what it has to say about *paragraphs*.

For more information about exactly what the sentence and paragraph commands do, see the source code defining them (in library `paragraphs.el`). Start, for example, with function `sentence-end`.

Comment: e.g.: `C-h i g` `(emacs) Expressions` `RET`